# How to know whether WebBrowser navigating a error page?

Tags: c#

for example, we navigating to http://www.ggg111.com, it's a error URL. but in WebBrowser it display a error page with this:

```
The webpage cannot be found 
 HTTP 400  
   Most likely causes:
There might be a typing error in the address. 
If you clicked on a link, it may be out of date. 

   What you can try: 
     Retype the address.  

     Go back to the previous page. 
     Go to  and look for the information you want.
```

how to know whether WebBrowser navigating a error page?

also check this:
https://sso.youshang.com/sso/userAuthnAction.do1

```
HTTP Status 404 - /sso/userAuthnAction.do1
type Status report
message /sso/userAuthnAction.do1
description The requested resource (/sso/userAuthnAction.do1) is not available.
```

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.  I see you tagged the question as C#-related.  Do you mean, how do you know if an embedded WebBrowser control request has generated an HTTP error code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on this control: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ExtendedWebBrowser.aspx

there is NavigateError function, fires when an error occurs during navigation.
here is my modified code:

add event argument class first:

```
public class NavigateErrorArgs : EventArgs
{
    public object StatusCode { get; set; }

    public NavigateErrorArgs()
            : base()
    { }

    public NavigateErrorArgs(object statusCode)
            : base()
    {
       this.StatusCode = statusCode;
    }
}
```

then add delegate and event in class ExtendedWebBrowser:

```
public delegate void NavigateErrorHandler(object sender, NavigateErrorArgs e);
public event NavigateErrorHandler NavigateError;

protected void OnNavigateError(NavigateErrorArgs e)
{
  if (NavigateError != null)
      NavigateError(this, e);
}
```

and modify method in class WebBrowserExtendedEvents:

```
public void NavigateError(object pDisp, ref object URL, ref object frame, ref object statusCode, ref bool cancel)
{
    _Browser.OnNavigateError(new NavigateErrorArgs(statusCode));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

not sure about this but,....
try it,...

```
string check = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
        if (check.IndexOf("The webpage cannot be found") > 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR OCCURED");
            //what else you want to do, do here!!!
        }
```

this will search for given text and if found will execute further code