# Can I know if Webbrowser-control returned "page not found"?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

This might be a yes or no question with a follow up:
When I use a Webbrowser-control, is there a way for me to know if it returned a "page not found" error? For example using the .ReadyState property?
If so, how?

If not, is there a simple method for doing this? Perhaps by checking page titles or something?

Answer (score 2):

The `LoadCompleted` event should get a `NavigationEventArgs` which contains the `WebResponse` which has the headers you can inspect.

Comment: This seems interesting.
Can I simply use it as if (webbrowser.NavigationEventArgs.WebResponse != null) ?
Or do I need to use a different syntax of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

> based on this control:
>   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ExtendedWebBrowser.aspx there is
>   NavigateError function, fires when an error occurs during navigation.

See the marked answer in this thread: [How to know whether WebBrowser navigating a error page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880811/how-to-know-whether-webbrowser-navigating-a-error-page)